# Positioning a table next to a floating image

Tags: css, image, css-float, tabular

I'd like to position a table next to a floating image while keeping the width of the table 100% and not overflowing the width of the parent element.

I've tried various techniques but haven't achieved the result I wanted yet. Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/AX3UR/3/

Any suggestions? Using the "overflow: hidden" property for #container is not a solution for me since essential information in table rows are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the table in a div, and float it left

See the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AX3UR/5/

Also your `h2` should not be in the `p`

**Edit**

I just noticed you wanted to keep the table 100% width. This is not easy with floating.
However you *could* use nested tables, but that has its on pros and cons.

See http://jsfiddle.net/AX3UR/13/ for a nested table solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a pitty though, that it's so tricky to do a rather simple thing.

Comment: @user1013696 you can do it a lot easier in CSS3

Comment: Already did. Any links to sources of the alternative in your mind?

Comment: @Juozas CSS3 `display: box` http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/